# Проблема сетевого доступа между подсетями

Tags: сеть, windows-7

Доброго времени суток! Проблема следующая: пытаюсь получить сетевой доступ от одной машины к другой через `//ip-address//$c`, получаю ошибку "windows не получить доступ к `//ip-address//$c`". При этом машина пингуется, я могу зайти на нее через `rdp`, могу подключиться к базе данных `MySQL`, а обычный сетевой доступ не работает. Машины находятся в разных городах и видимо находятся в разных подсетях (извините, я не силен в сетях). Хочу заметить, что когда машина подготавливалась в рамках одной сети, то сетевой доступ к ней имеется, также получается зайти на машины в соседних офисах, проблема появляется только когда машины находятся далеко. Еще один момент, проблемы один-два года назад не было, она появилась после обновления систем (возможно виноваты обновления win7).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите настройки общего доступа.

*Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Центр управления сетями и общим доступом\Дополнительные параметры общего доступа*

Попробуйте включить "Сетевое обнаружение" и "Общий доступ к файлам и принтерам"

Второй момент это брандмауэр или антивирус. Отключите его и попробуйте.

Comment: В дополнительных параметрах общего доступа эти параметры включены, брандмауэр отключен, антивируса нет.

Comment: А если посмотреть изначально вообще. Административные шары C$, $IPC, $Admin включены?http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2016/07/06/kak-vklyuchit-udalennyj-dostup-k-administrativnym-sharam-v-windows-10/

Comment: Так же, если у вас настроен сетевой доступ, то проверьте на наличие открытых портов на оборудовании, которое соответственно связывает офисы - протоколы: SMB и LanManager, NETBIOS  
Порты: 135, 137, 138 , 139, 445 на всякий случай.